# Stick div to border of another div so they stay together during resizing

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

How can I stick a Square in the middle of a border of another div? I've tried the following approach:

```css
.cont {
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
}

.square {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 0%;
  background-color: yellow;
  left: -5%;
  top: 25%;
}

.logoOnTheRight {
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
}

.logoOnTheRight img {
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont d-flex flex-row-reverse">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="logoOnTheRight p-2">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/sPuqd31g.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

In fullscreen Square 'sits' on the border as it's supposed to. But when I resize the page square changes position in such way that it doesn't stay on the border. I've noticed that if I specify `width` in the container `cont` by `px` then it works. But I want `cont` to be `100%` width. How can I force the Square to stay on the border of `cont` during page resize?

Comment: can you create snippet?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/37pfwauL/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `position: absolute` you position an element absolute without any relation to other elements.

If you want to position an element relative to another element then don't use `position: absolute` You can align your two elements to the left/right with flexbox like shown in the answer below. If you want different alignment of items you need to adapt the CSS to get the desired result. Just don't use `position: absolute` at all if you want to keep it responsive.

There are scenarios when you need `position: absolute` but this is not one.

In my example I used `display: flex` in combination with `align-items: center;` to align items in the center of the box. Check this link for [more information about flexbox.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

To move the box to the left you can use `transform: translateX(-50%);`

```css
.cont {
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.square {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 0%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: yellow;
}

.logoOnTheRight {
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
}

.logoOnTheRight img {
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont d-flex flex-row-reverse">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="logoOnTheRight p-2">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/sPuqd31g.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks good but how to style square on the middle of the border?

Comment: What do you mean how to style the square? You can target it via `.square { ...}` in your CSS. Sorry I'm confused.

Comment: Sorry, poor choice of words. I know how to position Square in the middle of the border using `position: absolute`. I don't know how to do it in your approach.

Comment: I edited my answer to add some more details, is this what you wanted to know?

Comment: Not exactly, if you look at my snippet the Square's center runs exactly on the border of container. I want it to be 50% inside container and 50% outside.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see this at first. You can use  `transform: translateX(-50%);` for this (updated my answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
.square {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 0%;
    background-color: yellow;
    left: -25px;
    top: 25%;
}
```

Instead of using `%` for `left` you can use `px`